# Force linear scaling of subscripts and superscripts

Tags: fonts, scaling

Perhaps I am being very picky but this font that I am using uses designed fonts for subscripts and superscripts when I want it to use scaled fonts. Their designed subscript and superscript fonts are too short and fat for my liking. Does anyone care enough to devise a way to force all subscripts and superscripts to use scaling instead of designed fonts? For example, a first level subscript or superscript will be scaled to 70% of the original font, instead of using another set of fonts that were designed specifically to be a sub/superscript.

To be more clear, I was talking about sub/superscripts for math only and yes i wanted scaled fonts for second-order sub/superscripts as well. The font I am mainly interested in is Math Time Pro 2 (the lite version) but it was more of a general question. The reason why I want this behavior is because I've read some books (such as Griffiths Intro to Quantum Mechanics, McQuarrie & Simon Physical Chemistry) that uses the old Math Time I believe, but not Pro 2 version so these books have linear scaling for the sub/superscripts (instead of designed sub/superscripts) and they look a lot better.

Comment: Please provide more information, e.g., about the font in question, whether you're using pdf/xe/lua-latex, whether this is about math and/or text in the superscripts, and whether you need to change both first- and second-order subscripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX chooses math font sizes with two mechanisms; the first one is through `\DeclareMathSizes` and `fontmath.ltx` (a file read in at format creation time) contains the following lines

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{7}{7}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{8}{8}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{7}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xviipt}{\@xviipt}{\@xiipt}{\@xpt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xiipt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxvpt}{\@xxvpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xviipt}
```

The command has four arguments

1. `#1` is a font size;
2. `#2` is the font size to choose when `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle` are in force, that is, for common symbols in formulas;
3. `#3` is the font size for first level subscripts and superscripts;
4. `#4` is the font size for second (and above) level subscripts and superscripts.

If the current font size matches one declared with `\DeclareFontSizes`, then LaTeX uses the stated font sizes. Otherwise it uses some heuristics: more or less, it uses the same font sizes in `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle`, 70% of it for first level {sub|super}scripts and 50% for second level ones.

Control sequences are used for sizes from 10pt upwards (actually `\@xipt` expands to `10.95` for historical reasons, for example).

Therefore, in order to change {sub|super}script sizes at 12pt size, you can simply state, in your document preamble,

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{7}{5}
\makeatother
```

Other similar declarations are necessary for each font size you use and in which you typeset formulas.

The package (`.sty`) that accompanies MathTimePro fonts should contain some of these declarations: look at them, because they are different from those in `fontmath.ltx`; an old version of `mathtime.sty` I have around contains

```
\DeclareMathSizes{5}     {6}   {6}  {6}
\DeclareMathSizes{6}     {6}   {6}  {6}
\DeclareMathSizes{7}     {6.8} {6}  {6}
\DeclareMathSizes{8}     {8}   {6.8}{6}
\DeclareMathSizes{9}     {9}   {7.6}{6}
\DeclareMathSizes{10}   {10}   {7.6}{6}
\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{10.95}{7.6}{6}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}   {12}   {9}  {7}
\DeclareMathSizes{14.4} {14.4} {10} {8}
\DeclareMathSizes{17.28}{17.28}{12} {9}
\DeclareMathSizes{20.74}{20.74}{14.4}{10}
\DeclareMathSizes{24.88}{24.88}{17.28}{12}
```

Recall that `\@xpt` is 10, `\@xipt` is 10.95, `\@xiipt` is 12, `\@xivpt` is 14.4, `\@xviipt` is 17.28, `\@xxpt` is 20.74, and `\@xxvpt` is 24.88

Here is an example, the five point size is just to show that the business works.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{5}{5}

\begin{document}
$A^{2}$---A\textsuperscript{2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Addition

If the problem is not to use the optical sizes provided by MathTimePro (Lite) fonts, the document preamble should override the settings in `mtpro2.sty` and related files:

```
% From mtpro2.sty
\DeclareFontShape{LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}{<-> mt2mit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP1}{mtt}{b}{it}{<-> mt2bmit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}{<-> mt2syt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{b}{n}{<-> mt2bsyt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{eb}{n}{<-> mt2hsyt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mtt}{b}{n}{<-> mt2mbt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2sya}{m}{n}{<-> mt2syat}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2sya}{b}{n}{<-> mt2bsyat}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2sya}{eb}{n}{<-> mt2hsyat}{}
% From umt2bb.fd
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2bb}{m}{n}{<-> mt2bbt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2bb}{m}{it}{<-> mt2bbit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2bb}{b}{n}{<-> mt2bbdt}{}
% From umt2hrb.fd
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2hrb}{m}{n}{<-> mt2hrbt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2hrb}{m}{it}{<-> mt2hbit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2hrb}{b}{n}{<-> mt2hrbdt}{}
% From umt2mf.fd
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2mf}{m}{n}{<-> mt2mft}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2mf}{b}{n}{<-> mt2bmft}{}
% From umt2ms.fd
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2ms}{m}{n}{<-> mt2mct}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2ms}{m}{it}{<-> mt2mst}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2ms}{b}{it}{<-> mt2bmst}{}
```

Not all font shapes may be defined in the Lite version.

Comment: The problem I am having is that when the superscripts take on say a size of 8pt or below it starts using a different set of fonts. This set of fonts are "designed" to be more clear so they are shorter and bolder. In your example, the "2" illustrates this: it is a much shorter looking 2 than a regular sized 2. So this is the thing I am complaining about. I want superscripts to use the same set of font as the 10pt set, only scaled by maybe 70% for the first order subscript and 50% so that the superscripts don't actually look short and fat. Sadly for me, "designed" superscripts are key features.

Answer (score 4):

For the current font, you can redefine the superscript macro. Same is possible for subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}

2\textsuperscript{nd} floor H\textsubscript{2}O

\makeatletter
\def\@textsuperscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize{5pt}\z@#1}}}}}
\def\@textsubscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\fontsize{5pt}\z@#1}}}}}
\makeatother
2\textsuperscript{nd} floor H\textsubscript{2}O

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a problem with the position of the apex and the subscript : `\newcommand{\Dparxx}[2]{\displaystyle \Fra{\partial^\textsubscript{2} #1}{\partial #2 ^\textsubscript{2}}}` and partial equation is : `\sum_{j=1}^{3}\Dparxx{u_i}{x_j} :\text{Laplaciano della velocità $\bar{u} = \Lapl{\bar{u}}$}}` . it is possible to establish the height of the apex and the subscript so that they have a smaller font but that they respect an aesthetically adequate position?

Comment: it make no sense in your case to use `\textsuperscript`. simply use `\partial^2`